# How to do transaction to buy air ticket from Wizz Air/Blue Air?

Tags: air-travel, europe, wizz-air, flying-blue

I am from India. I was trying to buy air tickets from the airline Wizz Air and Blue Air.
However my debit cards are not working during the transaction. I have international debit cards but that is also failing. My bank account is linked to PayPal but that is also not allowing to do the transaction. All the steps in transaction are successful, I am getting the OTP but finally getting failure. I contacted to bank and they said my international transaction is allowed. But nothing successful transaction.

There is one option of offline bank transfer but the Itinerary do not have all details in both the airlines. Also I am not sure how will they respond in such offline method. There might be long delay to confirm my ticket.

I know there are probably not much option I can do.

But still I would appreciate your suggestions.

At least can you give the email address where i can contact directly ?

Comment: Did you contact the airlines directly?

Comment: @DJClayworth, I did but didn't get any reply so far. Just said they have taken into note

Comment: bank transfer via wise.com ?

Comment: @chx, Is it safe option ?

Comment: completely, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably just that they had an hick-up in their system, and were not able to process your request. That can happen, I had it just last week with Air France, buy one ticket, fine, buy second ticket, failed, with any of four cards. Next day it worked fine.

Alternatively, (all) your cards do not allow international transactions. Your issuing bank would be able to tell you about that; and potentially change it; but it looks like this is not your issue.